# ember-data and how to trigger commit when all bindings and observers have updated?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Item model that has many Sections.     Each Item is stored in mongodb and the sections are embedded documents, so when I get an item the json contains the sections.

When I change a property in a section, a number of other sections can also change as they are bound to that property.

How do I save this change to the server after all bindings and observers have been completed ?

I don't really want my users to have to click a save button but I also don't want to save after each change as I will be saving after the change and also after the bound sections changes as well!

Hope this makes sense.

If anyone can show me an example of how to do this it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ember-data, you can create a `transaction` for that.  Once you have made all the changes on the `trasaction`, then, just call `transaction.commit()` to bulk update your changes.